# GIMP Script-Fu: "Error: (: 1) car: argument 1 must be: pair"

Tags: error-handling, batch-processing, gimp, script-fu, gimpfu

I'm rather new at using GIMP's script-fu, and I'm working on a script to go through a full folder of .tif image files, resize them to having a dimension a maximum size of 1200 pixels while maintaining the proportions of the image. It then will save the file as a .png filetype.

The problem I've encountered and can't seem to find an answer for is:

> Error: (: 1) car: argument 1 must be: pair

From what I can tell, it's saying that I'm trying to find the first entry of a list that doesn't have contents, but I don't see any further instances where this would be an issue. I've been pouring over numerous sites for help on this and tinkering with the script for around a while now, so I think it's time to ask for help. Unfortunately GIMP's documentation isn't very robust from what I can tell. Am I missing a car() somewhere that's still causing this error or is it referring to something more ambiguous now?

Thanks in advance...

```
(script-fu-register 
    "batchresize"            
    "Batch Resize"                                  
    "Resizes all images in folder to the desired maximum size and saves as .png"      
    "name"                   
    "(c) 2017"
    "March 2017"           
    ""
    SF-VALUE    "Maximum Dimension" "1200"   
    SF-STRING   "Target Folder"     "/Scripts/Input/*.tif"
)

(script-fu-menu-register "batchresize" "<Image>/File/Batch"
)

(define 
    (batchresize maximum targetfolder
    )

    (let* 
        (   
            (filelist 
                (car 
                    (file-glob targetfolder 1
                    ) 
                )
            )

            (width 1200
            )   
            (height 1200
            )
        )

        (while 
            (not 
                (null? filelist
                ) 
            )

            (let* 
                (
                    (filename 
                        (car filelist
                        )
                    )

                    (image 
                        (car 
                            (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename
                            )
                        )
                    )

                    (drawable 
                        (car 
                            (gimp-image-get-active-layer image
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )

                (Set! width car(gimp-image-width)
                )

                (Set! height car(gimp-image-height)
                )

                (if 
                    (> height width
                    )
                    (set! proportion 
                        (/ width height
                        ) 
                    )

                    (set! height maximum
                    )

                    (set! width 
                        (* maximum proportion
                        )
                    )

                    (if 
                        (< height width
                        )

                        (set! proportion 
                            (/ height width
                            ) 
                        )

                        (set! width maximum
                        )

                        (set! height 
                            (* maximum proportion
                            )               
                        )

                        (if 
                            (= height width
                            )

                            (set! height maximum
                            )

                            (set! width maximum
                            )
                        )

                        (gimp-image-scale-full image width height INTERPOLATION-CUBIC
                        )

                        (file-png-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable filename filename 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                        )

                    )

                    (gimp-image-delete image
                    )
                )
                (set! filelist 
                    (cdr filelist
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Your code is using `car` on functions that return a single element (`(gimp-image-get-active-layer image)`, but maybe not the only one). I'm surprised by your registration part, seems to be missing parentheses. Gimp can also be scripted in Python, with which you could be more familiar. But the whole project could be done directly with [ImageMagick's `convert` utility](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).